# Why does backslash get converted to space in echo statement if IFS='\'?

Tags: shell, shell-script, quoting

Why is `\` is converted to space on setting `IFS='\'`

```
var="'(]\\{}\$\""
IFS='\'
echo $var # '(] {}$"
```

Comment: Has nothing to do with the “\”,that stands for any character: http://pastebin.com/fycLjxrx And is not converted, is split on that character due to word splitting performed on unquoted strings.

Answer (score 3):

Because, that's what [`IFS`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) does. It is the Input Field Separator, bash will split unquoted strings on that character and you have set it to `\`:

```
$ var="fooAbar"
$ IFS='A'
$ echo $var
foo bar
$ echo "$var"
fooAbar
```